# Backing up a MySQL machine

Tags: mysql, backup

We used to have mostly MyISAM tables (only 1 InnoDB). Our backup solution uses `mysqldump`. However we noticed that sometimes the backup "broke" the site for a couple of minutes.

So we've switched to InnoDB, to have more reliable backups and remove the table locks that MyISAM uses.

Now I was wondering whether there are better ways to handle daily backups.

**Note**: Since we're using [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/), we can't use programs that need to run on the DB machine itself.

Answer (score 2):

Typical way to backup MySQL is to setup a slave MySQL instance and take backups from there instead of the master MySQL instance.

Comment: Amazon RDS has an extra slave (we use the Multi AZ deployment). But at the moment, we can't access it.

Answer (score 1):

[Xtrabackup](https://launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup) is the definitive Open Source backup utility for InnoDB.  [InnoDB hot backup](http://www.innodb.com/doc/hot_backup/manual.html) is the commercial counterpart, which was developed by InnoDB developers.

The slave replicant for nightly snapshots is a good recommendation as part of a full backup strategy.  This topic is covered well on Server Fault, I suggest you search.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look into [Zmanda](http://www.zmanda.com/backup-mysql.html) which doesn't require that you run on the same host as the MySQL server.